# Creating a front end file upload that works with the Files module

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads, safecracker-file, files

I'm trying to work out a way to allow users on the front end to upload a file. Not so difficult in itself but I then need to assign a category to that uploaded file.

Ideally I want to use the Files module but I don't know of a way to create an upload form on the front end that will use this module.

I could use regular entries and Safecracker but it's going to mean some retrofitting and fairly big changes in the existing site and methodolgy which I'd prefer to avoid.

Is there a way to do a front end upload form that integrates with the Files module?

Comment: What happens if Freeform lets you upload a file - does that get added to the Files module?

Comment: Hmm, don't know. I'll have a look. I've been discussing/mulling this over and I'm thinking I may need a different approach anyway and just use regular entries. But it will be good to find out what's possible.